# Node.js create array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a constant variable "client_id" and an array of variables called "device_list".
For example:

`client_id = "system1"
device_list = ['dev1' , 'dev2' , 'dev3']`

Now i need to combine both variables in order to receive an array like this:

```
result = [['system1' , 'dev1'],['system1' , 'dev2'],['system1' , 'dev3']]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you attempted to implement yourself something that does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a simple solution:

```
const client_id = "system1";
const device_list = ['dev1' , 'dev2' , 'dev3']

const result = device_list.map(device => [client_id, device]);
```

The map method is part of the array prototype.

It loops through every item in an array, and applies the given callback to each item.

For more information, I find the Mozilla docs extremely useful!:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Another thing to note:
  map is *NON*-mutative, meaning it doesn't affect the array on which it is called, it only returns a new one

Comment: The example almost speaks for itself, but it would be an even better answer if you described how it works.  Readers seeking answers to this problem may not be familiar with _map_ at all (since this is such a basic use case for _map_).

Comment: Thank you Wyck, you're probably right. I've added a short description and a link to Mozilla docs!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const result = device_list.map(device => [client_id, device])
```

This will map your existing `device_list` array to a new array, where each item consists of an array of `client_id` and device.

Comment: Wrong order: `client_id` goes first.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through the `device_list` array and return a new array like this:

```js
const client_id = "system1"
const device_list = ['dev1', 'dev2', 'dev3']
const result = device_list.map(d => [client_id, d])

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go over a `Array.prototype.map` here:

```
const result = device_list.map(function (item) { return [client_id, item]; })
```

It takes every element from `device_list` and returns an Array instead. Those are collected into a new Array `result`.